# compile error for map<int, int>::iterator, no match for operator =

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors, iterator, g++

I have the following code within the main() function

```
map<int, int>::iterator myvar;

. . .

if (myvar == 1) { . . . }
```

but when I compile, I get this error:

```
error: no match for âoperator==â in âmyvar == 1â
```

I inherited this code from a coworker who had this compiling before, so I'm curious if I have an incorrect compiler setting or do not have a needed library / package installed on my Linux machine.  Any ideas?

I've tried using const_iterator instead of iterator, but that didn't seem to be enough.  I also tried adding "typename" before the declaration, and that didn't help either.

Here's my g++ line:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror test.cpp -o test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is incorrect. You cannot compare an STL iterator with an integer.

If you want to compare the *key*, access it with `myvar->first`. If you want to compare the *mapped value*, use `myvar->second`.

Comment: Actually, I was boiling down my friend's code too far. He actually seems to have a later line where he re-casts the map as an integer somehow. I'll need to look at his code more carefully and re-post.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense, an iterator isn't a value you can compare against that way. What you probably mean to do is:

```
for(auto it = myVar.begin(); it != myVar.end(); myVar.next()) {
    if(it == 1) {
        //do something with it
    }
}
```

Or if you're just concerned with the very first value:

```
auto val = myVar.begin();
if(val == 1) {
    //use val
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was boiling down my friend's code too far.  He actually seems to have a later line where he re-casts the map as an integer somehow.  I'll need to look at his code more carefully and re-post.